# How can I return the item in Json array that is nested in another array in React Native

Tags: arrays, json, react-native

I have the Json array that I have to fetch in React Native. I can return the data in an array such as "name", "availability" but I can't return "url" in the array of media.data.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "attributes": {
        "name": "example",
        "availability": true,
        "createdAt": "2022-05-06T10:40:59.765Z",
        "category": {
          "data": [
            {
              "id": 8,
              "attributes": {
                "name": "category1",
                "createdAt": "2022-05-03T18:25:52.008Z"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "media": {
          "data": [
            {
              "id": 11,
              "attributes": {
                "name": "image.jpg",
                "alternativeText": "image.jpg",
                "caption": "image.jpg",
                "width": 550,
                "height": 550,
                "url": "https://example.com/image.jpg",
                "createdAt": "2022-06-01T07:56:15.031Z"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
      }
    }
  ],
}
```

This is my React Native code.

```
<FlatList
  data={notes}
  renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <View>
      <Text>Name: {item.attributes.name}</Text>
      <Image 
        source={{ uri: item.attributes.media.data[0].attributes.url }}
      />
    </View>
  )}      
  keyExtractor={item => item.id}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the example you provided the url is being accessed properly, but the image does not exist ([view for yourself](https://example.com/image.jpg)).

There are other steps you want to take ensure that url provided is being rendered. Give the Image a height and width so that in cases where the url actually exists, it is rendered to screen. Then for situations where the url doesnt exist, have a default image that you render to screen (like a question mark or broken link icon).

Here's a Image wrapper component I made that does this:

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Image} from 'react-native';

export default function MyImage(props){
  const [source, setSource] = useState(props.source);
  // make sure you specify image dimensions
  if(!props.style || !props.style?.height || !props.style?.width)
    props.style={
      ...props.style,
      width:40,
      height:40
    }
  return (
    <Image
      {...props}
      source={source}
      onError={({nativeEvent:error})=>{
        // onError set the source to another image
        console.log(error)
        setSource({uri:"http://clipart-library.com/images/8TxrBGznc.jpg"})
      }}
    />
  )
}
```

And your flatlist:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
// import RenderItem from './RenderItem'
import Image from './Image'
import data from './data.js';
const notes = data.data;


export default function App(props) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={notes}
        renderItem={({item})=>(
          <View>
            <Text>Name: {item.attributes.name}</Text>
            <Image 
              source={{ uri:item.attributes.media.data[0].attributes.url }}              
            />
          </View>
        )}      
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

Test it out [here](https://snack.expo.dev/oEzZqZ3Iv)